# How can I log the port that Spring Boot @ServiceConnection uses for container started with TestContainers?

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

In Spring Boot 3.2 I have this test configuration:

```kotlin
@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class TestBootstrap {


    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    @RestartScope
    fun mongoDbContainer() = MongoDBContainer("mongo")

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fromApplication<Bootstrap>().with(TestBootstrap::class).run(*args)
}
```

This works fine, but I'd like to also print the port that Spring/TestContainers use when starting the `MongoDBContainer`. For example, I'd like to print the port in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`:

```kotlin
@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class TestBootstrap {
    private val log = loggerFor<TestBootstrap>()

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    @RestartScope
    fun mongoDbContainer() = MongoDBContainer("mongo")

    @PostConstruct
    fun printPort() {
        println("I want to print the port here")
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method `getExposedPorts` to get the list of exposed port and `getMappedPort(int originalPort)` to get the mapped port. Anyway, for the common scenario of a container that only exposes one port(like MongoDBContainer that you created) you can use `getFirstMappedPort()` to check the mapped port.

```
@Bean
fun printPort(mongoDBContainer: MongoDBContainer): CommandLineRunner {
    return CommandLineRunner { _ ->
        println("Exposed Ports: ${mongoDBContainer.exposedPorts}")
        println("Mapped Ports: ${mongoDBContainer.firstMappedPort}")
    }
}
```